# Multiplying columns in a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable in C# with a "price" column and an "allocation" column, and I need to multiply the price column by the allocation column and put the result in the price column. Is there a way to do with without looping over the table? I have tried something like this:

```
DataTable dt = getData();
dt.Columns["Price"].Expression = "Allocation * Price";
```

But obviously this gives me the following exception:

```
Cannot set Expression property due to circular reference in the expression.
```

Does anyone know of another way to accomplish this?  Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What's wrong with looping over the table rows?

Comment: There could potentially be quite a few, I'm pulling this out of a General Ledger Database ;)

Comment: are you stuck with the datatable structure? why not have columns Price, Allocation, Total?

Comment: @SuperTron But even if you could set an expression, something somewhere has to go through each row and calculate those values.

Comment: @BWC Well, it is possible to do that way, but there are actually several columns I need to multiply, based on different things, so the "Total" might not always be indicative of what I need. I'd rather not have columns for "DebitTotal", "CreditTotal", etc. (Although that is what I will will fall back on if all else fails.)

Comment: @TimRogers Yes, thats true, but I would assume the C# built in DT functions are a little more optimized than what I could write :P

Comment: @SuperTron I doubt it very much. For one thing, the first thing it would have to do is parse and compile your string expression into something it understands. That's work it doesn't have to do otherwise.

Comment: @TimRogers That's a good point...

Comment: Ultimately you'll be looping through the rows of the Datatable the linq query mentioned is probably the cleanest solution as long as the values of the columns will always be able to be cast into doubles, if not then you may have to do some tryParsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a LINQ expression to do it in one line:

```
dt.Rows.ForEach(x => x["Price"] = (double)x["Price"] * (double)x["Allocation"]);
```

Comment: 4 upvotes for an approach that doesn't compile? A `DataRowCollection` is not a `List<DataRow>`. But please don't use `dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach`. The easiest and most efficient way is to use a  plain `foreach` loop.

Comment: This should also work...for some reason I was getting an error doing ForEach on rows.



dt.AsEnumerable().ForEach(x => x["Price"] = (double)x["Price"] * (double)x["Allocation"]);

Answer (score 2):

You could just add another column to the DataTable:

```
dt.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", typeof(decimal));
dt["TotalPrice"] = "Allocation * Price";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column whose value is calculated from the other two:

```
dt.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", typeof(decimal), "Allocation * Price");
```

With this approach, the `TotalPrice` will always be up to date if you change the `Price` or `Allocation`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a  seperate column, what happens when something makes the calculation execute again....

At some point the amount of code you have to add bend datatable to do what you want (without introducing a mass of potential 'erm features) will be more effort than just knocking up a class to hold the stuff.

Read from datatable write from databale isn't hard, nor is binding to a list of thingies.