# Create new C# DataTable Column as a function of Existing Column

Tags: c#

I start with a DataTable that is filled via a SQL query:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    sqlQuery = @Query;
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(table);
    }
}
```

I want to add a new column once I've filled the table via the data adapter.
This column needs to be a function of another existing column.

The function I want to apply to each row in the column is here:

```
Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml("*CONTENT* OF THE COLUMN")
```

My Desired output is as follows:

```
ID      |    Content                     |     New Column
0       |    *CONTENT* OF THE COLUMN     |     <p><b>CONTENT</b> OF THE COLUMN </p>
```

I tried using the following code per this question ([Multiplying columns in a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155613/multiplying-columns-in-a-datatable)):

```
table.Columns.Add("HTML_" + markdown_col, typeof(string), Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(markdown_col));
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Syntax error: Missing operand before '<' operator.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Missing operand before '<' operator.

Source Error: 


Line 132:                        foreach (string markdown_col in MarkDownCols)
Line 133:                        {
Line 134:                            table.Columns.Add("HTML_" + markdown_col, typeof(string), Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(markdown_col));
Line 135:                        }
Line 136:                    }
```

How do I add a new column that applies my function to the DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add the column once, after that you can access it with indexing. So, trying to follow what you're doing, the "markdown_col" is the name of the column with the markdown, and "HTML_" is the column name of the new column that you want to be HTML.

```
// Add column once
table.Columns.Add("HTML_", typeof(string));
// Loop over every row in the table
foreach(DataRow r in table.Rows) {
    r["HTML_"] = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(r["markdown_col"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I'll check it tomorrow then accept.